# How to call MATLAB script from command line?

Tags: bash, matlab

I have been trying to call matlab from Terminal (I have a Mac) and have it simply run a program for me, without display or anything, just the program. This program both displays graphs and writes a text file for me to use. I have found several of the previous answers on this question, and so I have tried:

```
   matlab -nodisplay -r foo 

   matlab -nodisplay -r foo.m 

   matlab -nojvm -nosplash -nodisplay -r foo;quit; 

   matlab -nojvm -nosplash -nodisplay -r "foo;quit;" 

   matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -r "foo;quit;" 

   matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -r
   "foo" 

   matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r foo
```

Pretty much every time I try it, I keep getting the same response (when the line just doesn't cause the prompt to say "screw you" and give up): the actual MATLAB program *window* will open, and it will stay open. It will interact normally. And command line won't do anything until I close out the window. The program I want doesn't run. The window just... sits there.

If it helps, this is how I have `matlab` coded in my bin:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                             

/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab
```

I have no clue what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try appending `exit` to your file (foo.m) and trying `matlab -nosplash -nojvm -nodesktop -r "foo"`.

Comment: Both with and without -nodisplay, it's a no go.

Comment: And does the script work as expected when called interactively from the matlab gui?

Comment: And what is the expected behaviour of a script producing figures if figures are disabled by a non-existent gui? BTW the terminal being unresponsive while matlab runs is perfectly normal, in linux you can get your shell prompt back by putting an ampersand (`&`) at the end of your command (but killing that terminal process can kill matlab running in it).

Comment: The script works normally when called from the GUI.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your `bash` script for calling Matlab will not pass any arguments to the Matlab executable. When you type

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "foo"
```

what is actually called is

```
$ /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab
```

without the arguments. There are several ways you can fix this whilst retaining the ease of just calling `matlab`. Alternatively you could call the full path to `matlab` like

```
$ /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "foo"
```

## Setting Up `matlab` Executable

### Bash Script

Given that you have already written a `bash` script to call `matlab` the easiest solution is to alter it to include the `$@` `bash` wildcard like

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                             

/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab "$@"
```

The `$@` wildcard passes all of the parameters you use, like `-nodesktop -nosplash -r "foo"` to the `matlab` executable so what is actually called now is

```
$ /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "foo"
```

I recommend you place your `matlab` `bash` script in `/usr/local/bin` and ensure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`. The `/usr/local/` directory is for user installed scripts as opposed to system installed scripts. You can check what directories are in your `PATH` with

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

and you should see an output similar to the above with `/usr/local/bin` present. The `bash` script should also be executable. You can set this with

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/matlab
```

**Note**: OS X El Capitan places strong restrictions on where scripts can be installed via its new [System Integrity Protection](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/09/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-the-ars-technica-review/8/#h1) feature.

### Creating a Symlink to `matlab`

Another method similar to the creation of the `bash` script is to create a symbolic link to the `matlab` executable. This again should be placed in `/usr/local/bin`

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/
$ ln -s /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab matlab
```

Also for this method you need to make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`.

### Adding `matlab` to the `PATH`

An alternative method is to simply add the directory where the `matlab` executable resides to your `PATH`. You can do this by modifying your `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc`) file. Your `.bash_profile` file resides in your home directory at `~/.bash_profile`. It is executed every time your user opens the Terminal. To add `matlab` to the `PATH` simply append

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/
```

to it. Now you can call `matlab` with

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "foo"
```

and this will locate the `matlab` executable in `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/` and call it with

```
$ /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "foo"
```

After you modify your `.bash_profile` file you need to reload it with

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

or restart the Terminal for the changes to take affect.

**Note**: I prefer to modify the `.bashrc` file instead of `.bash_profile` because I use `.bashrc` on Linux too. I have set my `.bash_profile` file up to load my `.bashrc` file

```
$ cat .bash_profile 
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

**Note**: If you want `matlab` to be available for every user and not just your user you need to add

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/
```

to the system-wide `/etc/profile` file.

### Creating an Alias for `matlab`

The last method I'm going to mention is creating an alias for `matlab`. We do this by again modifying our `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc`) file and appending

```
alias matlab="/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab"
```

to it. Again, after making changes we need to reload it with

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

or restart the Terminal for the changes to take affect. And, if you want `matlab` to be available for every user and not just your user you need to modify the system-wide `/etc/profile` file.

## Executing `matlab` from the Terminal

Now that we've set up `matlab` to conveniently execute from the Terminal with the simple command

```
$ matlab
```

we can look at actually executing scripts. To execute a Matlab script we first need to be in the directory where the script resides or it could be in our Matlab `PATH`. I'll assume it is not in your path and so we'll `cd` to the correct directory

```
$ cd /path/to/foo.m
```

Now to execute `matlab` without the desktop MathWorks tells us to use `-nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash` but if we use `-nojvm` and/or `-nodisplay` we won't be able to display graphs. So we drop `-nojvm` and replace `-nodisplay` with `-nodesktop` and use `-nodesktop -nosplash`. This will launch Matlab without a display and allow us to display graphs. The correct command then to execute `matlab` without the full desktop GUI whilst also allowing us to display graphs is

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -nosplash
```

Now you can use the Terminal (command prompt) as the Matlab command window and execute commands as normal. For instance we could call foo

```
>> foo
```

Alternatively, we can use the `-r` option for the `matlab` executable to pass in commands for Matlab to execute. **These must be quoted correctly and valid Matlab syntax**. So our command to start Matlab with our previous options and to execute the script `foo.m` becomes

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "foo"
```

**Aside**: If, for example, we were to use

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "foo; exit;"
```

(note the use of `exit;`) this would start Matlab, execute `foo.m`, display the graphs and then exit Matlab closing the graphs too.

Comment: THAAAAAAAANK YOOOOOOUUUU. This was driving me *insane*. (I wish it would let me award the bounty now.)

Comment: Yes. The huge amount of model analysis I have to do is vastly expedited by having this around. Thank you incredibly.

Comment: I actually need command line here. I'm running a perl script that regex search and replaces certain variables in the MATLAB script, then runs it, parses the data appropriately and stores and analyzes it in several different ways. The word "annoying" would not even begin to describe how annoying it would be to do this by hand.

Comment: Matlab 2019 adds the `-batch` option for non-interactive execution of script, statement, or function: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html

Answer (score 6):

I think the bash script ignores the command line arguments.
Could you try the following?

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -r "run foo.m;quit;"
```

Comment: Oh, good catch with the script! It might work if `matlab` was a `bash` `alias` instead.

Comment: Gave a syntax error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

Comment: Now it will pull up Matlab in the command line instead, but now it says "foo.m not found" even though I'm running the line while cd'd into the folder that has foo.m right there.

Comment: One or more of the following should catch: 1. `"addpath /your/script/path;run foo.m;quit;"`   2.  `"cd /your/script/path;run foo.m;quit;"` 3.  `"cd /your/script/path;foo;quit;"` 4.  `"addpath /your/script/path;foo;quit;"`

Comment: Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:
/my/path 
> In path (line 109)
  In addpath (line 88) 
Error using run (line 70)
foo.m not found.

Comment: When trying the cds, I get instead: Cannot CD to /Desktop/folder/ (Name is nonexistent or not a
directory).

Comment: Try to root cause it by running the command without the quit, and then try to run your script manually from the matlab prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -nojvm -r "foo($v1,$v2);exit"
```

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
#!/bin/bash
/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab < /path/to/foo.m
```

in other words use the `<` sign to re-direct, in Linux.