# Running MATLAB script from terminal Mac

Tags: macos, matlab, command-line, terminal, command

I am trying to run a matlab script from the terminal on MacOS. I am doing the following:
`/../matlab -nodisplay -r` 
to open matlab from terminal, then to run the script that is on a different path I write

```
cd ('/.../test/')
test1.m
```

It runs, I  get some error regarding the font. But I am not able to visualise the plots in the script, any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call MATLAB script from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187141/how-to-call-matlab-script-from-command-line)

Comment: If you want to display plots, you cannot use `-nodisplay`. The correct way since the last two years to run MATLAB from the command prompt is to use the `-batch` option. See [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabmacos.html).